# Am I obligated to chase after someone to pay them?

Tags: professional-ethics

We hired a tree removal service to remove some trees from our property. The bill was paid for by the solar company that installed our solar service. The solar company sent us a check for the tree service to use.

I signed the check and handed it over to the tree service promptly. Apparently they couldn't cash the check even though I signed it. They needed me physically there at the bank so that they could cash the check.

Busy schedules would not allow for that. They were too busy and so was I. So I told them to return the check to me and I would cash it and give them the money in cash (with receipt).

They took SIX MONTHS to return the check to me. By that time the check was stale and the bank wouldn't honor it.

So I had the solar company cancel that check, and issue a new one. I got the new check and and deposited into my account. Soon as it cleared I took out the cash.

Now I've been calling and texting the owner of the tree service to come get his money. He keeps texting he will call back, but he never does. It's been weeks of this!

So from an ethical standpoint, how much do I have to bug him to come get his money? If this goes on for another 6 months or however long, how much effort do I put into giving him his money?

It's $3,000 and I know the money isn't mine. But it will be sitting in a drawer in limbo forever if he doesn't come and get his money. He does not want a check he wants cash.

The owner from the tree server is driving the fact that I pay him in cash and meet him in person.

Comment: Yes it does. Thank you!

Comment: All-cash tree service deals are often tax-evasion schemes. You legally have the debt for a period of time, probably 3 years for an oral contract. Your question then seems to have become "can a contractor require me to drive to his place of business to deliver cash, at an inconvenient time, if that method of payment was not part of the contract?", or, simply, "can he refuse to accept my check?".